# how use the file inmediatly after use fs.createWriteStream with qr-image

Tags: node.js, filesystems

in my app i'm creating a qr image and then try to use it with jimp to combine the qr image on another image, but the fs.createWriteStream doesn't create the image immediately so subsequent lines of code try to use an image that doesn't exist.
here a part of the code:

```
var Jimp = require('jimp');
var qr = require('qr-image');

...

    var qr_png = qr.image(id, {type: "png",}); // id is an id on bd
    const qrPath = path.join(
                      __dirname,
                      `qr_image_${id}.png`
                    );
    const  mediaPath = qr_png.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(qrPath)).path.toString();
    // here the image in qrPath does not exist..
    Jimp.read(mediaPath, (err, lenna) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      // do somthing with qr image
    });

...
```

***But when the code finish and I go to the path the image is finilly created***

Answer (score 0):

solved creating Promise:

```
var Jimp = require('jimp');
var qr = require('qr-image');

...

    var qr_png = qr.image(`qr_image_${id}`, {type: "png",}); // id is an id on bd
    const qrPath = path.join(
                      __dirname,
                      `qr_image_${id}.png`
                    );
    await new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
                        qr_png.pipe(
                          fs.createWriteStream(qrPath).on("finish", resolve)
                        );
                      });
    // here the image in qrPath does not exist..
    Jimp.read(qrPath, (err, lenna) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      // do somthing with qr image
    });

...
```